# How can I attach a result of two linq queries

Tags: c#

I have two LINQ's which is below

```
public IEnumerable<TurbineStatus> turStatus()
{

    var result1 = (from s in _db.masterData
                  group s by s.current_turbine_status into g
                  select new TurbineStatus
                  {
                      status = g.Key,
                      numberOfTurbines = g.Count()
                  }
                ).ToList().OrderByDescending(s => s.status);

    int  result12= _db.masterData.Select(s=>s.turbine_name).Count();
    
    return result;


}
```

here is my TurbineStatus class:

```
public string status { get; set; }
public int numberOfTurbines { get; set; }
```

The first query returns me turbines with their status.

The second one returns me the number of all turbines.

How can I attach them together?

For example: the `result1` sample query result is("RUN":2,"STOP":4,...). That means that there are 4 turbines stopped and 2 turbines are running.

The second linq(result2) returns the number of all turbines, which is an integer.

Comment: Apart from that your second query looks bit strange to me. Why do you select the `turbine_name` and count the elements afterwards? Why not just `Count` without `Select`?

Comment: You could use an out param for your result list and return the number, or return a tuple or you could create a result-class with two properties, if that's what this is (and I think it is).

Comment: @HimBromBeereupdated my question

Comment: @Fildor can you explain more?

Comment: a `Status`-class that knows how many instances have that `Status` seems like a bad class-structure to me.

Comment: @HimBromBeere I'm curious, why is it a bad class structure ?

Comment: Another possibility: return `Dictionary<string, int>` which you can fill with `"RUN" : 2, "STOP": 4, "TOTAL": 6`

Comment: Because it breaks the responsible of a single instance of that class to know something about a **set of instances**.  Or in other words: why should a `Status`-class have a `Number`-property? I would expect a `Status` to be - well - just a `Status`, nothing else.

Comment: _"can you explain more?"_ - I was about to write up an answer with examples for each of the methods, I named. But the question has been closed :(

Comment: @HimBromBeere While I think you are absolutely correct about that observation, I think this discussion distracts a little from the question OP actually _has_. (No offense, as I said, I agree with you)

Comment: well, an answer to the question may also include something like "rethink your design, because...", IMHO.

Comment: @HimBromBeere Absolutely. _If_ it is going to be reopened, that is. :D

Answer (score 2):

You should rethink your class-structure. A single `Status` that knows about other instances of that class in order to count them breaks the Single-Repsoibility-Principle. So a `Status` is expected to be just a `Status`, not some aggregated information about other `Status` as well.

So I would recommend to make your `Status` just an enum:

```
enum TurbineStatus { OnRun, Stop }
```

Now group the turbines as you already do, but store the number of the items per status not in the status itself, but in a `Dictionary`, or even another class or - as in my code - in a tuple:

```
public IEnumerable<(TurbineStatus, int)> turStatus()
{
    var result = (from s in _db.masterData
              group s by s.current_turbine_status into g
              select (g.Key, numberOfTurbines = g.Count())
            ).ToList().OrderByDescending(s => s.status);

    return result;
}
```

or with a `Dictionary`:

```
public Dictionary<TurbineStatus, int> turStatus()
{
    var result = (from s in _db.masterData
                 group s by s.current_turbine_status into g)
                 .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value);
    return result;
}
```

However be aware that you can´t - or shouldn´t - order a dictionary. If you need that use a `SortedDictionary` instead.

If you also want the count of all items within the entire database, you may introduce an `out`-parameter as @Fildor suggested to either method. Or add another query after calling the above method:

```
var turstatus = turstatus();
var totalCount = turStatus.Select(x => x.Item2).Sum(); // assuming the first (tuple-based) approach)
var totalCount = turStatus.Select(x => x.Value).Sum(); // this is for the dictionary-based approach
```

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: As @HimBromBeere mentioned in comments, having a `Status` class, that actually "knows" how many instances of it there are is not so clean a design, so you may want to reconsider that.

That out of the way: "How do I return 2 separate things?"

1. Return + out param

```
     // signature of the function would be like this:
     int GetTurbineNumbers( out IEnumerable<TurbineStatus> ) // again: reconsider that class

     // the other way round
     IEnumerable<TurbineStatus> GetTurbineNumbers( out int totalTurbines )
```

Where you set the out-param to your list result and simply return the total number (or the other way round).

2. Create a result-class

```
class TurbineStatistics{
    public IEnumerable<TurbineStatus> {get; set;}
    public int Total {get; set;}
}
```

Create an instance, set the properties and return it.

3. Return a Tuple

```
     (IEnumerable<TurbineStatus>, int) GetTurbineNumbers()
```

4. **Return a Dictionary**

```
     IDictionary<string, int> GetTurbineNumbers()
     {
          // fill a dictionary with statusname, count and "total", count
          // return it
     }
```

Of course, instead of string you could also use a Status Enum as Key. It's just that that enum would have to have a "Total" item, which would again make it a little "dirty". What is a Status "Total" supposed to be. Of course, you could make a special enum "TurbineStatusStatisticItems" or something like that ... but I digress.

5. See HimBromBeere's answer.

Just to name a few possibilities.

**BUT** Ask yourself "should I do this *at all*?". A function, that returns "2 things" kind of destroys the "do *one* thing" principle. So, I personally would either: Have two separate functions for Status-Count and one for Total. OR chose one of the methods that *abstracts* the result, so that they aren't "2 things" anymore but *one set of statistical data*.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to do this

One way include the total in all the items in the list as follows:

```
public IEnumerable<TurbineStatus> turStatus()
{
    int  totalCount = _db.masterData.Select(s=>s.turbine_name).Count();

    var result1 = (from s in _db.masterData
                  group s by s.current_turbine_status into g
                  select new TurbineStatus
                  {
                      status = g.Key,
                      numberOfTurbines = g.Count(),
                      total = totalCount,
                  }
                ).ToList().OrderByDescending(s => s.status);

    
    return result;
}
```

OR

```
public class ResponseDto {
     IEnumerable<TurbineStatus> GroupData {get;set;}
     int TotalCount {get;set;}
}

...

public ResponseDto turStatus()
{
    int  totalCount = _db.masterData.Select(s=>s.turbine_name).Count();

    var result1 = (from s in _db.masterData
                  group s by s.current_turbine_status into g
                  select new TurbineStatus
                  {
                      status = g.Key,
                      numberOfTurbines = g.Count(),
                  }
                ).ToList().OrderByDescending(s => s.status);

    
    return new ResponseDto(){
         GroupData = result1,
         TotalCount = totalCount 
    };
}
```

OR with 1 Hit to DB

```
public ResponseDto turStatus()
    {
        var result1 = (from s in _db.masterData
                      group s by s.current_turbine_status into g
                      select new TurbineStatus
                      {
                          status = g.Key,
                          numberOfTurbines = g.Count(),
                      }
                    ).ToList().OrderByDescending(s => s.status);
       
        return new ResponseDto(){
             GroupData = result1,
             TotalCount = result1.Sum(t=> t.numberOfTurbines)
        };
    }
```

Comment: `total = totalCount,` honestly? A property that is equal on all instances of that class? Why even have that property? You don´t need it anywhere. This is a really bad design, IMO

Comment: _"There are two ways to do this"_ - I'd say this shows (in principle) _one_ way to do something slightly different.

Comment: I agree that the first option is not a great idea when data is large - That's why the other option was provided.
But it really depends on the scenario for small amount of data that would not be an issue. You are wasting memory space of (32 bit integer x n records).

You should also look at the other picture within this code -  there is more memory used up by calling ToList() . In a ideal code you should just stream using IEnumerable without calling ToList().

Comment: like the naming "ResponseDto"